# Is it required to lock every document in mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, interface, mongo-java-driver

I'm new to MongoDB. I was going through this link:

https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/query/

My question is:

What is the purpose of

```
iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {

    @Override
    public void apply(final Document document) {
        System.out.println(document);
    }

});
```

Can someone explain what is `Block` and `apply`?

I just want to read data present in mongodb. I don't want to alter the data present in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is optional way to manipulate `Documents` during iteration.

`Block` is a `Functional Interface` (Java interface)  which allows you to modify `Document` into custom object (add/edit/remove data, intialize your custom object, etc...)

So, `Block` has only 1 method called `apply` where you need to implement the `Document` manipulation. During iteration, `forEach` automatically calls `apply` method.

You can read more about functional interfaces: https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-functional-1

**EDIT:**

To use forEach more elegant, you can do:

1. Create new class which implements `Block<Document>`. So, for forEach method you can pass your class instance (`iterable.forEach(new DocumentImpl())`).

   ```
   public class DocumentImpl implements Block<Document> {

       public void apply(Document arg0) {
           //Do stuff here
       }

   }
   ```
2. Not recommended! Deprecated. Instead of using `MongoDatabase db`, use `DB db` where it works with `DBObject` interface. So, once you query with `find`, you will get `DBCursor`. You can iterate DBCursor by `.next()` and get `DBObject` documents.
3. Use Spring-Data which is more readable and maps your objects automatically between MongoDB and POJO. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html

Comment: Is there any other way other than overriding apply method ?

Answer (score 0):

The code is just reading all the documents from Restaurant collection and printing out each document on the console.